# is it possible to insert javascript into a google ad?

Tags: javascript, adsense, google-ads-api

I want to know if its possible to insert an external JS script into the code of a google ad in an adwords campaign. I want to do some sort of tracking and send that data to my server with ajax. Does google allow this? I couldn't find an answer on google sites.

Thanks

Comment: I seriously doubt it. Otherwise, I'd have seen `alert`s asking me to pay some attention to a specific ad, `window.location`s being changed, etc....

Answer (score 1):

Seems like **Not**

From adSense docs.

> Our program policies do not permit any alteration to AdSense code
>   which artificially inflates ad performance or harms advertiser
>   conversions. Your publisher account offers a number of options when
>   generating the ad code, which we hope will allow you to create an ad
>   layout that fits in with your site. In general, we recommend copying
>   and pasting the ad code. In some situations though, we understand that
>   modifications are crucial to a clean user experience.

AdSense doc [here](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354736?hl=en)

Comment: actually, this is not a `no`. It only forbids code that  `artificially inflates ad performance or harms advertiser conversions`. BTW - can you give a link to the source?

Comment: @WeaselFox: from what I can see in that link, the available modifications are extremely limited. For what you're trying to do: no.

Comment: @Cerbrus - yeah looks like you're right. This is also about the publisher changing the code, my question was about the advertiser inserting a JS tag.

Comment: Then my comment on your question seems accurate. Imagine the security issues a possibility like that would result in.

Comment: well `not` is probably correct,  but your quote from the docs is irrelevant, as it addresses the publishers side, and the question was about advertisers. thanks anyway